# Use a single button or image as an audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use an image as HTML5's audio player's play/pause button.

I don't need to show the controls. Is there any way I can do this, like hide the audio element and use Javascript or jQuery to play/pause the audio whenever the image is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use this:

**HTML**

```
<audio id="player">
  <source src="file.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

**JS**

```
var player = document.getElementById('player');
player.play();
```

and to pause

```
player.pause();
```

Let me know if you need any more help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out my player(STILL UNDER CONSTRUCTION): http://zachrip.net/p If you look at the source code you can see a lot of the essential things for making a music player. 
EDIT: I can also send you some basic source code if you want, I learn best by seeing and then copying down and then using it.